# Metallic Hydrogen vs. Nuclear Thermal Propulsion

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, space, space-travel, rockets

I'm trying to design a spacecraft (only 100-150 years in the future) that will carry a crew of astronauts (probably ≤10) on an extended mission through interstellar space (they have some sort of hand-wavy "Einstein–Rosen Drive" to help it cover these vast distances, don't worry about it), but they'll need some way to power the spacecraft while they're traveling between planets within solar systems or boosting in and out of planetary orbits, etc.

So, my question is: **is it better to use a metallic hydrogen propulsion system, or a nuclear thermal one?**

Work off of the assumption that metallic hydrogen *is* metastable at achievable pressures and temperatures. I understand that this is purely speculative, but let's just assume that it is metastable and that we've figured out a way to produce literal tons of the stuff.

Also assume that the spacecraft is pretty big—probably on the order of several hundred tonnes and is equipped with a stable, energy-producing fusion reactor.

A metallic hydrogen-fueled (mH) rocket engine could theoretically achieve a [specific impulse of 1700 seconds](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234900050_Conceptual_Launch_Vehicles_Using_Metallic_Hydrogen_Propellant), depending on a number of factors, of course, and the exhaust velocities may be in excess of 10,000 m/s. But we'll imagine that we've figured out how to optimize that number. The combustion chamber will likely exceed temperatures of 4000 K, but we can cool this using a mix of liquid hydrogen injected into the chamber and magnetic fields that contain the superheated plasma. Metallic hydrogen may also have applications as a powerful superconductor, and so it could also be used aboard the spacecraft to help contain the fusion reactor and generate power for the ship.

On the other hand, a nuclear thermal rocket (NTR), in particular, a [closed-cycle, gaseous core engine](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/enginelist2.php#ntrgasclosed) could have a very comparable specific impulse of 1500-2000 s, using only liquid molecular hydrogen as a propellant, with exhaust velocities of about 18,000 m/s. But an NTR has its own challenges that always come along when you're dealing with large amounts of fissile material. Radiation containment (which means more weight), dealing with waste, etc. Not to mention the trouble the astronauts would have to go through if the engine ever needed servicing.

While we can't know exactly how heavy a mH engine would be, it can probably be assumed to be somewhat lighter than the NTR. The mH engine would probably be much less complicated than the NTR, too: theoretically, all you would need to do is introduce the metallic hydrogen into the combustion chamber at the required temperature and pressure to break the metastability and *poof*, you've got thrust.

But, since this is going to be a very long mission, the ship is going to need a way to refuel. For the NTR, that's pretty easy. Send down a few detachable pods into the atmosphere of a gas giant, fill up on the very-abundant hydrogen gas, and then cool and compress it down so that it condenses into a liquid. For the mH engine, we don't really know exactly how to make large amounts of metallic hydrogen, but we can be pretty sure that's going to be difficult. Obviously the hydrogen gas can be mined from gas giants, but the temperatures and pressures required to produce metallic hydrogen, even assuming metastability, are probably *very, very* high. The sort of mechanism that could produce this is probably going to be pretty big and bulky.

So, to reiterate, **which propulsion system would be better for this mission?** Is it better do deal with the challenges of *in-situ* production of metallic hydrogen in order to decrease spacecraft weight/complexity? Or would it be better to use a nuclear thermal rocket engine in order to get a higher specific impulse, at the expense of added weight and having to deal with the troubles of radiation? Is the large mass of the spacecraft a factor in this, or will they be roughly the same?

I know that most of this is all speculation, but I'm trying to make this as hard sci-fi as possible, so any science-based opinions are much appreciated!

Comment: You have a fictional drive energized by a fictional power planet and you want us to provide hard science justification as to which non-existent power plant is better? I believe you're straining at the proverbial gnat. I also believe there isn't a worldbuilding question here. Remember, worldbuilding is about developing and consistently using the rules of a fictional world. Storybuilding (off-topic) is about plot, circumstances, and character choices. This Q is the later. Is there any way to reword the Q to be a worldbuilding question vs. a story choice?

Comment: I am digging it, but I think readers who appreciate you getting into the weeds as regards their impulse engines will be put off by handwaving the warp drive.

Comment: Getting hydrogen from gas giants is going to be difficult, dangerous, and expensive. It's much easier to crack water in bulk, and darn near every solid body out past the belt is made of mostly ice.

Comment: @Willk, that is a very valid point. The basic idea is that the "Einstein–Rosen Drive" works off of generating wormholes to cheat the FTL-barrier. Again, most of the science there is also very theoretical, but I would definitely like to dig into some more research with regards to that at some point and hopefully remove as much of the hand-waving as possible, or at least make it sound technically plausible

Comment: Have both systems in your world, but force the crew to use the NTR due to the refueling issue. The other one clearly seems better in your description, and you could have your crew Einstein-Rosening back home to refuel if you wanted, but independence is key in your description. That way you can emphasize the description in your storytelling and the characters can complain about using the inferior system. I'm not touching the physics of this one, though.

Comment: Note that specific impulse and exhaust velocity are the same thing, there's no point in mentioning them separately. In the case of mH, 1700s (~16.7 km/s) is a theoretical max value and 10 km/s is the Isp of the implementation proposed by the paper.